# Can I set privileges to certain files only having certain syntax in Java without using Regex library?

Tags: java, file, input, syntax

In my java program, the input consists of a .txt file. I wondered, how I can restrict this input to allow only the files, which fulfill a certain syntax.

E.g.
Syntax is 
`p(a) \n p(b)`
With a and b beeing variables. I want to allow files containing: 
`p(4) \n p("bla")`
but not files containing: 
`p(4) p("bla")`

Comment: You have files which contains `\n` in name of file?

Comment: do you want to check file name or its content??

Comment: If you don't want regex you can use String.indexOf. Search for the first text, search if you find a \n after your first text and so on.

Comment: @Dijesh I want to check the content of the files.